# Корректное сочетание слов в предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Есть предложение:

> При взгляде на этот странный дом у нее всегда урчал живот (урчало в животе).

Верно ли оно? Обычно так говорят, да, но если проанализировать, то, мне кажется, это неправильное предложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложение нормальное, хотя и напоминает отдалённо о типичной ошибке: ошибочным оно было бы с деепричастным оборотом ("Глядя на этот странный дом..." и т. д.), поскольку была бы нарушена связь депричастия и сказуемого (у них должен быть общий производитель действия).

Comment: Да оно не просто "отдаленно напоминает", оно вызывает почти столь же сильный  дискомфорт.

Comment: Дискомфорт может ощущаться разве что в неформально-разговорном варианте "урчал живот", но ошибки и здесь нет - никто ведь не станет уточнять "при её взгляде" или "при взгляде с её стороны": это излишество - ясно, что условие "при взгляде" относится к субъекту, а не к органу или к физиологическому процессу, который тот испытывает. Ещё меньше "дискомфорта" в точно такой же грамм. конструкции с другим словом: "при взгляде... у неё начинались судороги" (нет повода увидеть одушевлённость "живота"). А вот с деепричастием - прямой грамматический нонсенс (в современном понимании языка).

Comment: Нет, я не про урчаший живот. "Дискомфорт" возникает от живота ***глядящего*** (первым взглядом). Да, прямых указаний на грамматическую некорректность я пока не обнаружил, но субъективные ощущения не намного лучше чем от шляпы, проезжающей мимо станции. Просто случай со шляпой более частый и потому заслужил отдельного упоминания в списке грамматических ошибок. Но ведь грамматический запрет шляпы не на пустом месте возник, а именно на почве семантической неразрешимости сопоставления агента действия субъекту  (пациенсу). А у нас тот же случай неразрешимости, только с животом.

Comment: Такая проблема была бы в случае "**её** живот урчал", а здесь (**у неё** урчало в животе) проблемы нет, поскольку "при (её куда-то) взгляде" у неё же в организме происходил некий процесс, который можно по-разному сформулировать. Здесь нет возможности отнести взгляд к безличному действию, и остаётся отнести его к тому, к кому по смыслу же можно.

Comment: Я ж и говорил про "живот урчал", это было как вариант. Но про "урчало в животе" - тоже. Там немного по-другому, хотя суть та же. Чей взгляд-то? Вот представьте, что она - это архитектор или просто хозяйка этого чудовищного дома. Сама привыкла, но перед окружающими стыдно. *При взгляде постороннего - урчит.* Сравните: "На первый взгляд у неё урчало в животе" - вряд ли это взгляд хозяйки живота. Ну это я как пример. Странно, что вы этого не понимаете. Не просто не соглашаетесь (это я бы понял), но не чувствуете предмета, сути моих сомнений.

Comment: А фраза "при взгляде на... у неё начинала болеть голова (или возникала головная боль)" у вас тоже вызывает желание дополнительно уточнить, что это её взгляд, а не взгляд "головы" или "боли"? "Посторонний" и здесь может заметить, как она хватается за голову или причитает о мигрени :) .

Comment: Конечно. А в чем разница-то? Тут собака-то порылась не в животе или голове, а в несопостовимости грамматического подлежащего (живот или голова) логическому агенсу - производителю действия (взгляда). Бесспорной была бы конструкция повелительного наклонения "При проезде через мост, будь осторожен" - тут явного агенса нет, поэтому привязка обоих производителей действия к одному  субъекту сомнений не вызывает. Да и то - к стилю можно при желании и тут придраться.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы избегал подобных конструкций, особенно в варианте "урчал живот". Сам-то по себе живот может урчать, в плане сочетаемости вполне законная конструкция, путь даже и разговорная, но вот "при взгляде ... урчал живот"  возникает тот же "когнитивный диссонанс", что и в несогласованном деепричастном обороте. Кто глядел и кто урчал? Не знаю, можно ли считать ошибкой грамматической (хотя не исключаю), но стилистической погрешностью - почти наверняка.  Принципиально вопрос решается добавлением притяжательности: "При **её** взгляде... у неё урчал живот", но это в английском хорошо, в русском обилии местоимений подобного рода тоже смотрится стилистически грязновато.

У неё урчало в животе менее очевидно, но в принципе тоже неудачно по тем же соображением. Чей взгляд-то в этом случае?

Короче, если вопрос стоит "можно ли так писать", то не уверен, но не стал бы. А если "как можно улучшить?", то однозначно ***"При каждом взгляде на этот странный дом, она ощущала урчание в животе"***. Можно, наверное, и дальше улучшать.

Answer (score 0):

"Урчал живот" – так мы не говорим. В остальном с точки зрения грамматики все верно.